# How to create a certificate into a PKCS12 keystore with keytool?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, keytool, pkcs#12

I wanted to create a certificate into a PKCS12 keystore format with keytool program.

The keystore has extension `.pfx`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If the keystore is PKCS12 type (`.pfx`) you have to specify it with `-storetype PKCS12` (line breaks added for readability):

```
keytool -genkey -alias <desired certificate alias> 
    -keystore <path to keystore.pfx>
    -storetype PKCS12 
    -keyalg RSA 
    -storepass <password> 
    -validity 730 
    -keysize 2048
```

Comment: The key of the question is that if the keystore has extension .pfx you have to add the option -storetype PKCS12 Without this option keytool throws an error.

Comment: When using `keytool -list`, be sure to append the `-storetype PKCS12` to see the `Keystore type: PKCS12` in the result, rather than `Keystore type: JKS`.  See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801921/295260).

Answer (score 4):

Additional answer to the *key of the question*.

With JDK 8 (*1.8.0_121-b13*) you don't get an exception if you remove `-storetype pkcs12` but the `keytool` creates a `JKS` keystore instead, and the `.pfx` extension is ignored.

It also asks for a `-keypass mykeypassword` which the `keytool` doesn't support for PKCS12.

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -genkeypair -alias mykey -keyalg EC -dname "cn=CN, ou=OU, o=O, c=C" -validity 365 -keystore keystore.pfx -keypass mykeypassword -storepass mystorepassword -v

(translated)
Generating keypair (Type EC, 256 Bit) and self-signed certificate (SHA256withECDSA) with a validity of 365 days
    for: CN=CN, OU=OU, O=O, C=C
[keystore.pfx saved]
```

List the contents:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -list -keystore keystore.pfx -storepass mystorepassword 

(translated)
Keystore-Type: JKS
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore contains 1 entry.

mykey, 25.04.2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate-Fingerprint (SHA1): A1:6C:5F:8F:43:37:1A:B6:43:69:08:DE:6B:B9:4D:DB:05:C9:D5:84
```

You see it's a Java keystore.

The next problem is, that even if you specify `-storetype pkcs12` when you `-list` the keystore, the keytool will still display the store as a JKS keystore!

Let's try that:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -genkeypair -alias mykey -keyalg EC -dname "cn=CN, ou=OU, o=O, c=C" -validity 365 -storetype pkcs12 -keystore keystore.pkx -keypass mykeypassword -storepass mystorepassword -v

(translated)
Warning: No support for different keystore and key password for PKCS12 keystores. The value of -keypass will be ignored.
Generating keypair (Type EC, 256 Bit) and self signed certificate (SHA256withECDSA) with a validity of 365 Days
        für: CN=CN, OU=OU, O=O, C=C
[keystore.pkx saved]
```

Now list the contents:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -list -keystore keystore.pkx -storepass mystorepassword

(translated)
Keystore-Type: JKS // ??
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore contains 1 entry

mykey, 25.04.2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate Fingerprint (SHA1): EA:C2:36:C6:55:69:CB:32:22:C7:14:83:67:47:D2:7E:06:8E:13:14
```