# keytool reports a pkcs12 keystore as 'jks'

Tags: java, keytool, pkcs#12

keytool is reporting `Keystore type` as `JKS`. Expected it to be `PKCS12`.

```
$ $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which keytool)))/java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
$ keytool -genkey -storetype PKCS12 -keystore foo.p12 -dname "CN=foo" -storepass password -keypass password
$ keytool -list -keystore foo.p12 -storepass password

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

mykey, 18/10/2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): FD:2A:C7:EE:B4:D8:41:91:71:25:C2:3F:8D:89:11:6F:F8:D6:F3:73
```

Is this the correct way to create a pkcs12 keystore?

Answer (score 3):

Cannot reproduce:

```
C:\Temp>keytool -genkey -storetype PKCS12 -keystore foo.p12 -dname "CN=foo" -storepass password -keypass password

C:\Temp>keytool -list -keystore foo.p12 -storepass password
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

C:\Temp>java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Temp>keytool -list -keystore foo.p12 -storepass password -storetype PKCS12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 1 entry

mykey, 18/10/2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 3F:C2:78:0D:E5:8D:11:68:2E:EB:31:D3:65:53:69:9F:
87:65:63:3A
```

> Is this the correct way to create a pkcs12 keystore?

Yes, but it's not the correct way to list it. You need `-storetype PKCS12` as per my last example above.

Comment: ...I'm going to note that you're testing it on a different version of Java than they are using.

Comment: Yep. Getting same result as @EJP on jdk 1.7.0_151. Seems with keytool, it's a case of 'if I want your opinion, I'd give it to you'

Comment: Getting same result as in the answer with `java version "1.8.0_151"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   -storetype <the value of the “keystore.type” property in the
    security properties file, which is returned by the static
    getDefaultType method in java.security.KeyStore>
```

If you check your java.security file, you will likely see that the default value for the keystore.type is jks.  The 'keystore type' is being picked up by the value assigned in the java.security file, and not from the keystore itself.