# Setting image form field

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I created a sample PDF form with one image field. I'm trying to set an image to the field using PDFBox.

I see that PDFBox treats such field as an instance of `PDPushButton` but I don't see this class' interface exposes methods to deal with images...

The sample PDF can be downloaded using the URL in comment.

How can it be done?

---

**EDIT**:

Here is what I'm doing so far:

```java
PDDocument pdfDocument = null;
PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
if (acroForm != null) {
    PDPushButton field = (PDPushButton) acroForm.getField("test");

    PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("my_img.png", pdfDocument);

    List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = field.getWidgets();

    /*
     * The field may appear multiple times in the document, I would like to repeat that for every widget (occurence).
     */
    for(PDAnnotationWidget widget : widgets) {
        PDRectangle rectangle = widget.getRectangle();

        //PDAppearanceDictionary appearanceDict = widget.getAppearance();
        /*
         * In my case, when the image is not set with Acrobat DC, appearanceDict is null.
         */

        /*
         * Create the appearance stream and fill it with the image.
         */
        PDAppearanceStream pdAppearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(pdfDocument);
        pdAppearanceStream.setResources(new PDResources());
        try (PDPageContentStream pdPageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdfDocument, pdAppearanceStream)) {
            pdPageContentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, rectangle.getLowerLeftX(), rectangle.getLowerLeftY(), pdImageXObject.getWidth(), pdImageXObject.getHeight());
        }
        pdAppearanceStream.setBBox(new PDRectangle(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight()));

        /*
         * Create the appearance dict with only one appearance (default) and set the appearance to the widget.
         */
        PDAppearanceDictionary appearanceDict = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
        appearanceDict.setNormalAppearance(pdAppearanceStream);
        widget.setAppearance(appearanceDict);
    }
}

ByteArrayOutputStream outStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdfDocument.save(outStr);
pdfDocument.close();
```

However, the generated PDF doesn't show any image with Acrobat Reader.

My goal is to start with [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1balEQf_P6_KPsJGMGUH3jejLVL5wHFds/view?usp=sharing) and use PDFBox to get [this PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUZeYaMdKBnNOMfrOmGjNtqR7uMkbf0r/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13QCyxxZvYjRQ4I5tP4-6c7bAPCtsCaHz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The reason for this is that the pdf standard does not contain image fields at all! Certain proprietary pdf generators / editors (Adobe products in particular) are using java script to make push button fields to operate similar to form fields in a GUI, in particular in their own pdf viewers. Nonetheless those push buttons are push buttons, not form fields, so *PDFBox treats such field as an instance of `PDPushButton`*...

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking then to put a dummy text field in the PDF where I want the image to be. Then, I get the coordinates of the textbox and create an image at this position. However I can't find any documentation...

Comment: In spite of my stressing that using push buttons as "image fields" is proprietary I think that - if you really need something like an image field - there is no need to find a different solution to emulate image fields, one can simply follow Adobe's lead. One merely has to be aware that one merely emulates image fields.

Comment: The truth is that I need to insert an image that represents a signature... So, if there is a different way to do it, I would be glad to hear. The thing is that I don't need (and even want I guess) the digital properties of the signature, I'm only interested about the image.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, the pdf standard ISO 32000-2 does not specify "image fields" at all. Certain proprietary pdf generators / editors (Adobe products in particular) are using JavaScript to make push button fields to operate similar to form fields for images in a GUI, in particular in their own pdf viewers. Nonetheless those push buttons are push buttons, not image form fields. Thus,

> PDFBox treats such field as an instance of `PDPushButton` but I don't see this class' interface exposes methods to deal with images...

If you really need something like an image field, though, there is no need to find a different solution to emulate image fields, one can simply follow Adobe's lead. One merely has to be aware that one only *emulates* image fields.

To fill the push button field with an image, one can use the `AcroFormPopulator` [Renat Gatin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3898122/renat-gatin) presents in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820098/1729265) to his own question ["How to insert image programmatically in to AcroForm field using java PDFBox?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46799087/1729265).

Beware, though, applied to your sample file it reveals a bug in the PDFBox form flattening code. Thus, you should deactivate form flattening in the `AcroFormPopulator`, i.e. remove the `acroForm.flatten()` in it.

<sub>The bug in question is due to a missing transformation: If an XObject is used as appearance of a form field, everything in its bounding box by specification is automatically moved into the annotation rectangle:</sub>

> <sub>1. The appearance’s bounding box (specified by its **BBox** entry) shall be transformed, using **Matrix**, to produce a quadrilateral with arbitrary orientation. The *transformed appearance box* is the smallest upright rectangle that encompasses this quadrilateral.</sub>
>
> <sub>2. A matrix *A* shall be computed that scales and translates the transformed appearance box to align with the edges of the annotation’s rectangle (specified by the **Rect** entry). *A* maps the lower-left corner (the corner with the smallest *x* and *y* coordinates) and the upper-right corner (the corner with the greatest *x* and *y* coordinates) of the transformed appearance box to the corresponding corners of the annotation’s rectangle.</sub>
>
> <sub>3. **Matrix** shall be concatenated with *A* to form a matrix *AA* that maps from the appearance’s coordinate system to the annotation’s rectangle in default user space</sub>

<sub>*(ISO 32000-2, section 12.5.5 Appearance streams, Algorithm: appearance streams)*</sub>

<sub>When said XObject after flattening is referenced from the page content, this transformation *AA* is not anymore determined and applied automatically by the viewer, so it has to be explicitly added by the form flattener.</sub>

<sub>Apparently PDFBox form flattening at least does not create that *AA* matrix, in particular it assumes the bounding box lower left always to be at the origin of the coordinate system.</sub>

<sub>For your example PDF this is not the case, so flattening here effectively moves the flattened image field button off-screen.</sub>

<sub>PS: The situation is even weirder than expected, `PDAcroForm.flatten(List<PDField>, boolean)` does try to determine whether translation or scaling of a former appearance XObject is necessary and adds a transformation if it thinks it to be required but</sub>

<sub>1. when checking the need for translation in `PDAcroForm.resolveNeedsTranslation(PDAppearanceStream)`, it actually checks the form XObject resources of the appearance XObject; if and only if there is an XObject among them with a bounding box with neither anchor coordinate being 0, it is assumed that no translation is required. — This is a very weird test, a proper test would have to check the bounding box of the appearance XObject itself, not of form XObjects it contains. In the sample document the appearance XObject does not contain any form XObjects, so translation is automatically assumed to be required.</sub>

<sub>2. when adding a translation transformation, it again ignores the bounding box of the the appearance XObject and translates as if the appearance XObject anchor was at the coordinate system origin. — In the sample document this is completely inadequate as the bounding box anchor is already located that far out, causing it to be relocated to twice the required distance from the origin.</sub>

<sub>3. when checking the need for translation in `PDAcroForm.resolveNeedsScaling(PDAppearanceStream)`, it actually checks for the presence of contained arbitrary XObjects and assumes that scaling is required if there is such a contained XObject. — In the sample document there is an image XObject, so scaling is assumed to be necessary... weird.</sub>

<sub>These 3 details make no sense at all. (Well, there may have been some sample documents for which they by chance give rise to the desired result, but in general this is nonsense.)</sub>

Comment: I'm sure that Tilman has spotted it here. And on several similar occasions he turned such SO answer parts into Jira issues... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> The truth is that I need to insert an image that represents a
>   signature... So, if there is a different way to do it, I would be glad
>   to hear. The thing is that I don't need (and even want I guess) the
>   digital properties of the signature, I'm only interested about the
>   image.

Did you know that you can directly add an image to a PDF file?
But if you need a signature, then I would say use a signature form field. **Don't misuse** any other fields. And if you really don't need the features of a signature then flatten the document afterwards and the image remains but the signature is gone. But lots of our customers want something like this in the beginning but after some questioning and consideration they decide to go use real signatures...

This is what you need to do:

1. [Create a keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375185/how-to-create-a-certificate-into-a-pkcs12-keystore-with-keytool) (best use pkcs12)
2. Add a [signature field](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateEmptySignatureForm.java) to your PDF
3. Sign the field (or do it in one step with step 1)

   ```
   KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
   keystore.load(new FileInputStream("YourPathToAKeyStore.p12"), "pw".toCharArray());

   File documentFile = new File("YourPdf.pdf");
   CreateVisibleSignature signing = new CreateVisibleSignature(keystore,"pw".toCharArray());

   FileInputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream("imageOfTheSignature.png");

   signing.setVisibleSignDesigner(-85, imageStream);
   imageStream.close();
   signing.setVisibleSignatureProperties("name", "location", "Security", true);
   signing.setExternalSigning(externalSig);

   signing.signPDF(documentFile,new File("signed.pdf"),null,"SignatureField10");
   ```
4. `<optionally>` flatten the document

Comment: but if he flattens the document, then the signature would be invalid, isn't it?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr More to the point, flattening removes the digital signature, merely the ink signature remains. So if eventual flattening is part of the work flow, there really is no need to use an actual signature field and apply cryptography...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The signature wouldn't be invalid in a technical matter - it would just be gone (invalid is if you would change the document and leave the signature inside, so that the checksum check fails and a reader would report: "invalid signature") But legally it is another question...