# Spring Boot existing domain .cert file implement my application (SSL)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an ssl certificate for a purchased domain. I want to apply this to my spring boot application. How can I implement this?
I only found self-singed samples and looking for CA signed certificate (with extension **.CERT**) implementation example(s).

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the keystore starting from your certificate:
   `keytool -import -alias myAlias -file certificate.cert -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass password -storetype PKCS12`
2. Add the generated keystore file to your classpath (eg. under `src/main/resources`)
3. Add the following properties to enable SSL:

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=myAlias
server.port=8443
```

Comment: This will result in having a jks keystore, because you have to specified the storetype paramter: -storetype pkcs12. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43603501/7033189

Comment: You're right, must've overlooked it. I'll edit the answer, thanks.